# Java applet: How to make sure destroy is finished before page refresh

Tags: java, applet, logging, handler, java.util.logging

In Java util logging, I initiate the handler on init(), and close the handler at destroy() and it works perfectly fine: A log file was created, etc. If the user refreshs the page normally, it still just creates one log file.

However if the user refreshs the page with the applet a couple of times fast, it seems like the destroy() does not get called or maybe hasn't finished the task and since the init() gets called again, it assumes the previous file is still locked and creates a new log file.

I tried to use both destroy() and finalize() to close the handler but it does not work.
Anyone has any idea how to solve this issue?

Another minor question is: What actually happened if init() has not finished and the page gets refreshed. Is it going to continue the process and eventually failes to call destroy() or does it just stop right there?

Comment: Could you add to the question code of your "init" and "destroy" methods? At least parts about log handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/appletExecutionEnv.html):

> The Java Plug-in software creates a worker thread for every Java
> applet .

In multithreaded environment you should be very careful with shared resources. Best and easiest approach is not to share anything (scales best and no deadlocks possible).

I assume, that you initialize your handler each time in "init"-method. If it's true, you should use one static shared logger (check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915448/using-synchronization-while-logging)). It will help to improve situation a bit, but if you start more than one browser with your applet - new log file still will be created. And this workaround is not recommended by Oracle and preserved for backward compatibility.

---

Recommended and easy to implement solution - "each applet should have it's own logger and write to own file". Code for log file name generation:

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

private String generateFileName() {
    return String.format("applets-log/%s-%s.log", dateFormat.format(new Date()), UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

Also, [Best Practices For Applet Development](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/best_practices.html).

---

Answer to your minor question (**changed**):

According to discussion of this [old bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6840201) in java plugin, applet could be terminated at any moment with some predefined interval for cleanup. So you should put resource cleanup code in your "stop" or "destroy" method, but you shouldn't rely what that code will be executed.

> Applets lifecycle is controlled by browser and applets should not be
> given capabilities to run when its hosting document is destroyed by
> browser.
>
> Since 6u10, both old plugin and new plugin enforce applet shutdown
> after a fixed amount of time (1000ms in old plugin and 200ms in new
> plugin) for applet to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are not testing in FF. Read here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638070

Comment: that is not the case, as the applet works perfectly normal, no matter how many times you press refresh, the applet still functional. It just it does not kill the lck file, and cause to create multiple log files

Answer (score 0):

You've simply run into a fundamental limitation with multi-threaded environments.

You really cannot tell when `destroy()` or `finalize()` will be called relative to other threads. When the browser reloads the page, it may load the applet in a new thread.  If the user hits reload twice quickly, it may create 2 new threads, call `init()` on the 2nd one (which the user actually sees) before calling `init()` on the one the user never sees and before calling `destroy()` on the previous one.  At the other end of the life cycle,  `finalize()` is called by the garbage collection thread possibly very long after the object is no longer needed.  You are working in a multi-threaded environment and you cannot count on any order of operations between threads.

To quote the Javadoc:

> An applet is a small program that is intended not to be run on its own, but rather to be embedded inside another application.

It is really the outer application that should control creating/opening and closing the log if you are going to have only one log file. **If the outer application is a web browser, then you cannot solve the problem you are having.**  Then again, if you are running the applet in a web browser, you should not be writing logs to the file system.  That is just generally impolite behavior.

If you absolutely had to have log files for applets inside a web browser, the easiest solution is for each call to `init()` to create a new file specific to that invocation of the applet.  If you wanted to get ambitious you could use lock files to indicate which files were in use and at `destroy()` time concatenate the unlocked log files into one bigger one, but then again you have the problem of coordinating the concatenation processes across threads.

Comment: You are wrong about `If the outer application is a web browser, then you cannot solve the problem you are having`. Logging frameworks (JUL, log4j and etc) are thread-safe to use. So problem could be resolved using static shared logger which will be used by all instances of applet.

Comment: @Vadim you cannot guarantee the browser will only call your static initializer once.  The browser is free to create a new applet class loader and reload your applet on every refresh, thus calling the static initializers each time. Even if in practice it does not do it, you should not rely on static initializers being called only once as a way to synchronize between applet instances. What if, for example, you had the same applet loaded on the same computer at the same time in two different browsers, say Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Static variable initialized by JVM, at the time when class loaded. I don't expect problem with classloader in this SO-question, so I switch to discussion of JVM. If user starts 2 different browsers - each browser starts its own JVM. Also new JVM could be started if applet requires specific JRE or specific JRE parameters (this condition is OK for current question, because we discussing one applet, so JRE requirements and params will be the same). So, shared static variable will work in case of one browser and problem from question will appear in the case of several browsers.

Comment: For ideal solution I think it's also possible to use file system as shared object (looks like JUL uses that solution with all this "lck"-files created while logging). But it will be harder to implement. For me - `don't run 2 different browsers with my applet simultaneously` is a reasonable restriction.

Comment: @Vadim, you and I disagree about expecting problems with the classloader in this situation.  A browser should do everything it can to keep applets from talking to other applets running in the browser, and one of the best ways to do that is to use separate classloaders for each applet instantiation.  Note that it is the classloader, not the JVM, that calls the static initializers.

Comment: [Classloader Cache and Interaction between Applets](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_execution.html#cache). Class loader caching is enabled by default.

Comment: My point is that although it's not recommended, but it's still working (thanks to backward compatibility). And also other solution possible, but not for beginners.